# Nasty unintelligible error when trying to sort map values by putting in vector

Tags: c++

I have a `WordEntry` class which has a `unordered_map<string, int>`, and I want to store the frequencies of each word. I am able to do so, but I also want to display to the user the top 5 words and bottom 5 words. To do this, I must sort. However, I get a really awful, nasty, error that isn't like your normal c++ exceptions. I am not sure if including it would be of much help, as it is fairly long. Here is my `wordentry.h`

```
#ifndef WORDENTRY_H
#define WORDENTRY_H
#include "node.h"
#include "bst.h"
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class WordEntry
{
public:
    int retrieveWordFreq(Node<T> *);
    void collectWords(T data);
    void getTop5();
    void getBot5();
    unordered_map<T, int> freqs;

private:
    int freq = 0;
    bool sortByVal( pair<string, int> &a,  pair<string, int> &b);
};

template <class T>
int WordEntry<T>::retrieveWordFreq(Node<T> *word)
{
}

template <class T>
void WordEntry<T>::getTop5()
{
    vector<pair<string, int>> vec;

    // copy key-value pairs from the map to the vector
    unordered_map<string, int>::iterator it2;
    for (it2 = freqs.begin(); it2 != freqs.end(); it2++)
    {
        vec.push_back(make_pair(it2->first, it2->second));
    }

    // // sort the vector by increasing order of its pair's second value
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortByVal);

    for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i > vec.size() - 6; i--)
    {
        cout << vec[i].first << ": " << vec[i].second << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void WordEntry<T>::getBot5()
{
    vector<pair<string, int>> vec;

     for (auto& it : freqs) {
        vec.push_back(it);
    }

    
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortByVal);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << vec[i].first << ": " << vec[i].second << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void WordEntry<T>::collectWords(T val)
{
    freqs[val]++;
}

template <class T>
bool WordEntry<T>::sortByVal(pair<string, int> &a,  pair<string, int> &b)
{
    return (a.second < b.second);
}
#endif
```

and my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include "bst.h"
#include "wordentry.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string word, filename;

    BST<string> wordTree; 
    unordered_set<string> set; 
    WordEntry<string> words; 

    filename = "file.txt";
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    
    while (file >> word)
    {
        wordTree.insert(word); 
        words.collectWords(word); 
    } 
    
    cout << "Words amount: " << wordTree.length() << "\n";
    cout << "Unique Words amount: " << set.size() << "\n"; 
    
    words.getBot5(); 

    int choice; 
    
    cout << "What do you want to do?\n1. Enter a word and find it's frequency\n2.Output frequency analysis to a file\n"; 
    cin >> choice; 
    if (choice == 1) {
        string word; 
        cout << "Enter the word you want the frequency of \n"; 
        cin >> word; 
        for (auto x : words.freqs)
        {
            if (x.first == word)
            {
                cout << x.second; 
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        ofstream outfile ("output.txt"); 
        outfile << "Words amount: " << wordTree.length() << "\n";
        outfile << "Unique Words amount: " << set.size() << "\n"; 
    }
    
    
   return 0; 
    
}
```

`words.getBot5();` is the main culprit, meaning my implementation is wrong, but I am not sure why. I am just copying the key pairs to a vector and sorting.

EDIT: Here is the error

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from driver.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 
'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > 
>; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1844:14:   required from 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; 
_Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1882:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1968:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4739:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)]'
wordentry.h:62:9:   required from 'void WordEntry<T>::getBot5() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
driver.cpp:34:19:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:123:18: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>::_M_comp) (...)'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 
'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Value = std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _Compare = bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:129:48:   required from 'void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with 
_RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Distance = int; _Tp = std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:230:23:   required from 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; 
_Distance = int; _Tp = std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:335:22:   required from 'void std::__make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1669:23:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1930:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, 
std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1945:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Size = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1965:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4739:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Compare = bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)]'
wordentry.h:62:9:   required from 'void WordEntry<T>::getBot5() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
driver.cpp:34:19:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:144:11: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (WordEntry<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>::_M_comp) (...)'
  { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You are seven keystrokes away from the answer -- `s`, `t`, `a`, `t`, `i`, `c`, <space>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things differently.

First you have to make your comparator `static` like this:

```
template <class T>
class WordEntry
{
public:
//    int retrieveWordFreq(Node<T> *);
    void collectWords(T data);
    void getTop5();
    void getBot5();
    unordered_map<T, int> freqs;

private:
    int freq = 0;
   static bool sortByVal( pair<string, int> &a,  pair<string, int> &b); // static
};
```

Because normal member function pointers are more complicated than static member functions because they need an object to operate on.

Secondly you have to refer to it with its qualified name:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), WordEntry<T>::sortByVal); // qualified name
```

Answer (score 0):

***This can be done without sorting the list, and run significantly faster, especially for large lists.***

To get the largest or smallest item you scan the list once and track one variable.  If you find an entry that is larger than your current largest, just copy it into largest. If you find an entry that is smaller than your current smallest, just copy it into the smallest.

Given an array of size `N`, the following pseudo-code finds the largest or the smallest.

```
Copy = array[0];

foreach Entry in array
  if searching for largest and Entry > Copy, set Copy = Entry
  if searching for smallest and Entry < Copy, set Copy = Entry
```

When this code finishes, Copy contains either the largest or smallest.  The runtime for this code is `O(n)`, while sorting first and taking largest or smallest runtime is `O(n * lg(n))`

For any fixed size `K`, you just make Copy an array of size `K`. The pseudo-code changes only a little.

First we postulate existence of a function `Find_S_or_L_In_Copy()` that returns the index of the smallest or largest item in the Copy array.

Second, we use this function to help track the smallest or largest `K` items.

```
foreach Slot in Copy
  Copy[Slot] = Array[0]

foreach Entry in Array
  if searching for largest K
    set Item = Find_S_or_L_In_Copy()
    if Entry > Copy[Item], set Copy[Item] = Entry

  if searching for smallest K
    set Item = Find_S_or_L_In_Copy()
    if Entry < Copy[Item], set Copy[Item] = Entry
```

When this new code exits, the array `Copy` will contain the `K` largest or smallest entries from `Array`.  The runtime for this code is `O(N * K)`.